# how to get a notification for every checkin in clearcase for a particular Vob

Tags: clearcase

In our project so many file changes are happening, I want some notification for every checkin. so that every one in the team can know the files changed in the project.
I want some basic information about the file like comments and the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means "trigger": specifically a post-op checking trigger:

```
cleartool mktrtype -c "Trigger to notify on checking" -element -all -postop checkin -execwin "ccperl \\path\to\notification\script" -execunix "Perl /path/to/notification.pl" NOTIFY_ON_CHECKING
```

You can get some ideas from the ["ten best triggers" IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4311.html).

See also the [E-mail notification postoperation trigger script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_pstop_scrpt.htm), which is on deliver, but that can also give you a good idea for adapting it for each checkin.