# clearcase Trigger not working in client

Tags: triggers, clearcase

clear case trigger implemented and working in server but while trying in client it's throwing below error - this trigger prevent from unreserved checkout

error checking out
M:\view_main\xxx\abcd.java
can't execute "C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl //\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl";
the system cannot fine the specified file
Trigger action "-exec "C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl //\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl"
unable to run : Exec format error
unable to check out "M:\view_main\xxx\abcd.java"

Comment: error checking out
M:\view_main\xxx\abcd.java
can't execute "C:\Program Iles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl \\server\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl";
the system cannot fine the specified file
Trigger action "-exec "C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl \\server\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl"
unable to run : Exec format error
unable to check out "M:\view_main\xxx\abcd.java"

Answer (score 0):

A trigger script must be accessible by all clients.

It is best to declared it in an UNC path (a shared path `\\server\folder\path\to\script`).
That way, the script is accessible from any client able to access and read the content of that shared path.

See for instance an example at "[Creating a ClearCase trigger to disallow checkins for certain Rose RealTime versions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237378)".
I also used that technique in "[how to get a notification for every checkin in clearcase for a particular Vob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185411/6309)".

Comment: [-exec "C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl ] this is server clearcase ccperl location [\\server\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl] this is shared path client able to access ; why still i am getting error

Comment: @Aki because do you get the exact same error message? Can you copy it?

Comment: error checking out
M:\view_main\xxx\abcd.java
can't execute "C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl \\server\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl";
the system cannot fine the specified file
Trigger action "-exec "C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin\ccperl \\server\trigger\trig_reservedonly.pl"
unable to run : Exec format error
unable to check out "M:\view_main\xxx\abcd.java"

Comment: @Aki try using `ccperl` instead of the full path (`C:\Program FIles\IBM\RatinalSDLC\Clearcase\bin` should be in the client `%PATH%`)