# ClearCase moving triggers scripts to another location

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I have to move the trigger's scripts from one server to another, on both linux and windows.
As far as i know i have to use the `ct mktrtype` command with the `-replace` parameter, I've read on IBM web site that i have to use the same command that was used to create those triggers.
How can i identify the command that was used.
Here is part of my triggers:

```
trigger type "REMOVE_EMPTY_BRANCH"
 2007-11-27T15:29:00+02:00 by vobadm.ccusers@tlv-vob2
  "Automatically remove empty branches"
  owner: ARRS\vobadm
  group: ARRS\ccusers
  all element trigger
  post-operation rmbranch, rmver, uncheckout
  action: -execunix /usr/bin/perl -I /tlv-vob2/triggers/lib /tlv-vob2/triggers/rm_empty_branch.pl
  action: -execwin \\tlv-vob2\perl\bin\perl -I \\tlv-vob2\perl\lib -I \\tlv-vob2\triggers\lib \\tlv-vob2\triggers\rm_empty
_branch.pl
trigger type "RESTRICT_BASELINE_OPS"
 2007-11-28T13:20:20+02:00 by vobadm.ccusers@tlv-vob2
  "Restrict normal users from creating baselines, unless they are performing a rebase or deliver"
  owner: ARRS\vobadm
  group: ARRS\ccusers
  all UCM object trigger
  pre-operation mkbl, chbl, rmbl
  action: -execunix /usr/bin/perl -I /tlv-vob2/triggers/lib /tlv-vob2/triggers/mkbl_pre.pl
  action: -execwin \\tlv-vob2\perl\bin\perl -I \\tlv-vob2\perl\lib -I \\tlv-vob2\triggers\lib \\tlv-vob2\triggers\mkbl_pre
.pl
  excluded users: vobadm,amason,builder
trigger type "UNCO_POST"
 2007-11-27T15:29:00+02:00 by vobadm.ccusers@tlv-vob2
  "Safely remove empty branches on uncheckout"
  owner: ARRS\vobadm
  group: ARRS\ccusers
  all element trigger
  post-operation uncheckout
  action: -execunix /usr/bin/perl -I /tlv-vob2/triggers/lib /tlv-vob2/triggers/unco_post.pl
  action: -execwin \\tlv-vob2\perl\bin\perl -I \\tlv-vob2\perl\lib -I \\tlv-vob2\triggers\lib \\tlv-vob2\triggers\unco_pos
t.pl
```

I need to move the triggers to this path:
Windows: \poseidon01\clearcase\triggers, \poseidon01\clearcase\perl
UNIX: //tlv-vob3/triggers ///usr/bin/perl

Answer (score 0):

It should be something (from [`cleartool mktrtype` man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm?lang=en) and [this older example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185411/6309))

```
cleartool mktrtype -replace -element -all -postop rmbranch,rmver,uncheckout -execwin <windows_path> -execunix <unix_path> "REMOVE_EMPTY_BRANCH"
```

Comment: I just want to make sure that i understand you.
Is it the correct command:
`cleartool mktrtype -replace -element -all -postop rmbranch,rmver,uncheckout -execwin \\poseidon01\clearcase\perl -I \\poseidon01\clearcase\perl\lib -I \\poseidon01\clearcase\triggers\lib \\poseidon01\clearcase\triggers\rm_empty_branch.pl -execunix /usr/bin/perl -I /tlv-vob3/triggers/lib /tlv-vob3/triggers/rm_empty_branch.pl "REMOVE_EMPTY_BRANCH"`

Comment: Yes, the only part I don't fully remember is if you need quotes around the windows and unix path/command.

Comment: where should i specify the vob name ?
When i;m using the `ls` command `cleartool lstype -long -kind trtype -invob \my_pvob`
i'm specifying the vob name

Comment: I usually execute the command in the right vob of a view: the command will use the current vob of the current view.

Comment: Let's say that i don't have a view on my machine is there any option to run it ?