# Can I remove version-0 of a file on a ClearCase branch without a trigger?

Tags: branch, clearcase, cleartool

Suppose I've checked-out a file `foo` on a ClearCase view, which triggered the creating of a version of that file with branch name `my_branch` - the first version for that file with that branch name. Now I've un-checked-out the file - but version-0 of it with that branch name remains. How can I remove it? I know there's some way to do it using a "trigger" (I'm not quite familiar with those); can I just remove it manually with some command?

Note: `my_branch` has versions of other files on it; it shouldn't be removed entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Manual removal of a single version-0 file

For a single file, as requested in the OP:

The (dangerous) command would be [`cleartool rmver`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/bs/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm)

```
cleartool rmver util.c@@/main/my_branch/0
```

That would be the manual approach, assuming `my_branch` is created from `main`.

As [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19552030/6309), in order for the version to
*not* leave any dangling element (branch, label, hyperlink or attribute metadata), you would need:

```
cleartool rmver –xbranch –xlabel –xattr –xhlink util.c@@/main/my_branch/0
```

(assuming the version 0 is the only version on that branch)

#### Manual removal of all files on a branch

As I mentioned in "[how to remove a version in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295888/6309)", if you have inadvertently created some version-0's on a branch, the better way to remove them - all of them - is to use [`cleartool rmbranch`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmbranch.htm):

```
"cleartool rmbranch -force $myBranch"
```

You can see it used in "[Command to delete branches of Clearcase element with “0” versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18183902/6309)".
But that would be for the all branch indeed. Not for a single file.

#### Automatic removal

The automatic approach is put in place through a mktrtype, as [I documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27906615/6309).
As a script, you can use:

- [`cc/triggers/RemoveEmptyBranch.pl`](https://github.com/adefaria/clearscm/blob/62f779395c2f0a72a065b5a2caeaff88be420aa6/cc/triggers/RemoveEmptyBranch.pl) or
- [`clearcase/triggers/RemoveEmptyBranch.pl`](https://github.com/adefaria/defaria.com/blob/da7f9f3e9ce09b82a04fbcf357a770d4c6a76401/Computers/code/bin/clearcase/triggers/RemoveEmptyBranch.pl)

That does use a trigger: I mention it here just for the sake of completeness, even though it is not your preferred approach.
For a occasional cleanup, `rmver` is enough for a lone 0 version.
(for any other case, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172187/6309), `rmver` is dangerous)

Comment: Removing the 0 version on a branch will either fail or leave a dangling branch instance. Use cleartool rmbranch instead.

Comment: @BrianCowan True. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @BrianCowan: But I don't want to remove the branch globally, I just want to remove the 0-version for a specific file on that branch. Isn't rmver my practical alternative?

Comment: @einpoklum Good point. I have edited the answer to make the choice clearer between the two approaches (branch vs. file)

Comment: @BrianCowan: Why would rmoving version 0 fail? And why would it "leave a dangling branch instance" if other files are on that branch?

Comment: @VonC: But this question is not about removing the entire branch. I made it pretty clear but will clarify further.

Comment: @einpoklum Agreed. This is for other readers, to illustrates there are two approaches to consider. For the rmver one (for a single file), you might need to use more option on rmver in order to not leave any dangling elements (ie: branches, labels, hyperlinks, attributes): see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19552030/6309.

Comment: @einpoklum I have put back rmver as the first choice in this answer, since it fits your question. I have put rmbranch in last, for completeness sake.

Comment: @einpoklum Rmver on a zero version may fail if it's the ony version on the branch, because in that case removing the branch is more appropriate. A zero version is -- by definition -- identical to its predecessor version on its parent branch. It is almost never necessary to remove the .../branch/0 version of an element if there are .../1, .../2, etc., versions.

Comment: @BrianCowan: Ok, but I specifically said I have other files on the same branch. As for my motivation - it has to do with not prefering the new-branch version over more up-to-date version on the base branch (i.e. a later configspec rule).

Comment: @einpoklum "Files on a branch" is more the way Perforce and GIT work. Branches are in the forefront in Perforce, and GIT branches whole snapshots. Branches are parts of elements in CC, which makes it a bit challenging at times. Generally speaking, if the only version on a branch of a file is the \0 version, you want to get rid of it because you may want to see the newer versions. Intentionally mkbranching a whole raft of files to "freeze" them is a bit redundant since labels would have the same impact...

Comment: @BrianCowan: I was just mis-phrasing my comment. It should be "I have other files which have versions with the same branch".

Comment: @einpoklum Removing a branch from one file element will not impact other file elements at all. Other SCM tools (GIT and perhaps Perforce) where branches are front-and-center will behave differently if files are unique to the branch and aren't in the "trunk"/"master"/"main" branch. "Elements" (Files and directories) are front-and-center in CC, and the paradigm difference is somewhat confusing when going between systems.

Comment: @BrianCowan: Branch types are not per-file in ClearCase.