# Send email on every check-in in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

In my project there are multiple developers onsite as well as offshore who keeps on checking-in their code continuoulsly. Being the Build Engineer, I want to get the notification on every check-in with the developer name in Clearcase. As I am new to Clearcase please tell me step-by-step process what I do to achieve this as I am working on Window Platform.

I have already gone [through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183976/how-to-get-a-notification-for-every-checkin-in-clearcase-for-a-particular-vob) this but I didn't understand from where I start and how. Please advise me the step by step process, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: I have added some explanations, and updated the email script link in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185411/6309), you start by registering the post-op trigger in the vob you want to see that trigger run on each checkin.
You do that by using a dynamic view in which you mount the vob.

```
cleartool start anyDynamicView
cd m:\anyDynamicView
cleartool mount \aVobTag
cd aVobTag
cleartool mktrtype...
```

The script must be in a shared path accessible both from the vob server and by the Windows clients.

Comment: of which script you are mentioning here. And how can i make the window OS to send mail as CC is installed on same. And I am only working on static view so can still it be possible.

Comment: @R.Sha I am referring to the script I linked in my original answer: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_pstop_scrpt.htm. It is a perl one, so it should work on Windows or Unix, provided you have access to the smtp of your company.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still I am confusing as where should I put the script on windows CC. Do i need to go to Administrator console or there is a direct link og triggers in CC somewhere. Please help.

Comment: @R.Sha "where should I put the script on windows CC" in a shared path which is accessible both from the Windows client and the ClearCase server.